# PHP ignored when calling views bulk operation from rules

Tags: rules, views

We have a view with a Global PHP filter that returns the uid of users based on the contextual filter's date received from a rule (set to run weekly, once).

The view on work fine with arguments on it's own, but seems to ignore the custom PHP filter we've included, once it's called from rules.

Not quite sure what the issue is or if it's simply a bug.

Comment: are you sure Rules is sending the correctly formatted contextual filter?

Comment: What does Rules debug information tell you?

Comment: Is it possible to provide more details about that "rule" in your question here? E.g. by editing the question to include that rule (in rules export format).